# Using regular expressions in python to determine C++ functions and their parameters

Tags: c++, python, regex, parsing, doxygen

So I'm doing something wrong in this python script, but it's becoming convoluted and I'm losing sight of what I'm doing wrong.

I want a script to go through a file, find all the function definitions, and then pull out the name, return type, and parameters of the function, and output a "doxygen" style comment like this:

```
/******************************************************************************/
  /*!
    \brief
      Main function for the file

    \return
      The exit code for the program
  */
/******************************************************************************/
```

But I'm doing something wrong with the regular expression in trying to parse the parameters... Here is the script so far:

```
import re
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1])

functions = []

for line in f:
  match = re.search(r'([\w]+)\s+([\S]+)\(([\w+\s+\w+])+\)',line)
  if line.find("\\fn") < 0:
    if match:
      returntype = match.group(1)
      funcname = match.group(2)
      print '/********************************************************************'
      print "  \\fn " + match.group()
      print ''
      print '  \\brief'
      print '    Function description for ' + funcname
      print ''
      if len(match.groups()) > 2:
        params = []
        count = len(match.groups()) - 2
        while count > 0:
          matchingstring = match.group(count + 2)
          if matchingstring.find("void") < 0:
            params.append(matchingstring)
          count -= 1
        for parameter in params:
          print "  \\param " + parameter
          print '    Description of ' + parameter
          print ''
      print '  \\return'
      print '    ' + returntype
      print '********************************************************************/'
      print ''
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is going wrong?  What are the symptoms?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a parser for this?

Comment: C++ source does not play well with regular expressions. Try looking at the signature of a function that returns pointer-to-member-function type. Why not just use doxygen? It's customizable.

Comment: Well, yes. I want to use to doxygen. I just want to write a script that will go through and blast out some templates of the doxygen comments for me. As far as the "symptoms" of what's going wrong, it just isn't grabbing the parameters correctly, which is probably because I started having trouble and the expression just became convoluted. I guess I don't really understand how to pull out multiple parameters into the match.group(). Anyways thanks for any help anyone can provide

Comment: Also interested if anybody has a suggestion of a better way to do this.

Comment: @Robert Kelly, do not ever parse anything with regular expressions. They're not fit for this purpose. Use a parser. But be warned, C++ syntax is the worst of all syntaxes ever invented, even if you're only going to detect top level declarations you'll face a number of ambiguities. For this reason, your only choice is to reuse an existing parser - say, Clang, GCC, Open64 or Elsa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar of C++ is far too complex to be handled by simple
regular expressions.  You'll need at least a minimal parser.
I've found that for restricted cases, where I'm not concerned
with C++ in general, but only my own style, I can often get away
with a flex based tokenizer and a simple state machine.  This
will fail in many cases of legal C++—for starters, of
course, if someone uses the pre-processor to modify the syntax;
but also because `<` can have different meanings, depending on
what precedes it names a template or not.  But it's often
adequate for a specific job.

Comment: Wow thanks I'd never even seen anything like flex before. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a PEG parser with great success when trying to do simple format parsing.  [pyPeg](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/) is a very simple implementation of such a parser written in Python.

Example Python code for C++ function parser:

**EDIT: Address template parameters.  Tested with input from SK-logic and output is correct.**

```
import pyPEG
from pyPEG import parseLine
import re

def symbol(): return re.compile(r"[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&*][\w:]+")
def type(): return symbol
def functionName(): return symbol
def templatedType(): return symbol, "<", -1, [templatedType, symbol, ","], ">"
def parameter(): return [templatedType, type], symbol
def template(): return "<", -1, [symbol, template], ">"
def function(): return [type, templatedType], functionName, -1, template, "(", -1, [",", parameter], ")" # -1 -> zero or more repetitions.


sourceCode = "std::string foobar(std::vector<int> &A, std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > &B)"
results = parseLine(sourceCode, function(), [], packrat=True)
```

When this is executed results is:

```
([(u'type', [(u'symbol', 'std::string')]), (u'functionName', [(u'symbol', 'foobar')]), (u'parameter', [(u'templatedType', [(u'symbol', 'std::vector'), (u'symbol', 'int')]), (u'symbol', '&A')]), (u'parameter', [(u'templatedType', [(u'symbol', 'std::map'), (u'symbol', 'std::string'), (u'templatedType', [(u'symbol', 'std::vector'), (u'symbol', 'std::string')])]), (u'symbol', '&B')])], '')
```

Comment: Good luck parsing template arguments with this.

Comment: Granted PEGs can't do everything, but the OPs questions was function arguments not template arguments.

Comment: Function arguments and return values can be of template instance types.

Comment: True.  But for documentation are you planning on using the instance type?  That would make for BIG document.  Plus if you look at how the OP is wanting to use the tool, the OP only wants to document the function, not each instance of the function due to template instance types.

Comment: Without being able to parse all the possible C++ types you won't even *detect*  a function definition. Try parsing this: `std::string foobar(std::vector<int> &A, std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > &B)`

Comment: With a small change to the 'symbol' rule above, your example could be parsed very easily for the **purpose of the question**.  All of what you are saying is true.  But your responses are irrelevant to what the OP is trying to accomplish.  The OP is trying to extract data for documentation purposes.  For that you do not need a full blown C++ parser.  Look at Doxygen, WinMerege, and various other code formatters.  None of these tools have, nor require a C++ parser, they recognize patterns.

Comment: @Aaron Smith, without a full parser you may get a lot of false positives, for example. And why writing an incomplete parser if there are so many complete parsers already available? Btw., your rule will miss nested template parameters, e.g. `std::vector< std::pair<int, int> >`. Needless to mention that you certainly might want documenting template methods too, which makes parser even more complicated.

Comment: @SK-logic, again, a small change to the rule set would fix this case.  The company I work for requires PDL (dear God!) for each and every function.  I used this approach to dynamically create PDL for every function in our code base (2.5 million lines of code).  It took me 20 minutes and 250 lines of python.  No false positives.  Why use the Ferrari approach when using the Pinto will get me to the same conclusion with a lot less money and time?

Comment: @Aaron Smith, small change here, small change there - and no guarantee yet that it is perfect. Too much work for such a simple task which requires 10 lines of shell. And let me guess - your codebase is in C or "C with classes", not a hardcore C++ with tons of Boost, horrible macro hacking and Microsoft extensions?

Comment: @SK-logic, actually 2/3 of the code base is in C++, 1/3 in C, and yes we use Boost.

Comment: @SK-logic, see update with "simple" change.  This correctly parses the test input you've provided.

Comment: @Aaron Smith, now what about ellipsis and default parameter values? What about attributes (especially type-annotated ones)? What about arrays, plain good old C arrays? And so on, and so on. This crappy C++ language is so huge that building a reasonably good parser for just its declarations syntax is too much of a work. PEGs are cool and powerful, but even with such a tool it is too much. On the other hand, gcc-xml will do it all for you for free, in no time.

Comment: @SK-logic: We can go can go around and around on this forever.  Granted PEGs can't do everything, I'm in agreement with you here.  Since the OP is using Python, I was showing the OP a possible Python approach.  I'll leave it up to the OP to determine what best fits their need.  And yes, gcc-xml will also work, but the OP did not mention what compiler they were using.

Comment: @Aaron Smith, that's actually what I am doing in cases like this - calling gcc-xml or clang (until its xml printer was maliciously removed) from small python scripts. No matter which compiler is used for building, any "proper" compiler is much better than any handwritten incomplete one. It allows to take care of the evil macros at least (e.g., things like `void EXPORT_DEF(foobar)(int arg)`). For any other language than C++ I'd go your way, with a simple handwritten parser (e.g., I've got a whole bunch of tiny tools for Fortran). But C++ is different.

Comment: @SK-logic: Just had to get the last word :)

Answer (score 0):

C++ cannot really be parsed by a (sane) regular expression: they are a nightmare as soon as nesting is concerned.

There is another concern too, determining when to parse and when not to. A function may be declared:

- at file scope
- in a namespace
- in a class

And the two last can be nested at arbitrary depths.

I would propose to use [CLang](http://clang.llvm.org/) here. It's a real C++ front-end with a full-featured parser and there are:

- a C API, with (notably) an API to the Indexing Library
- Python bindings on top of the C API

The C API and Python bindings are far from fully exposing the underlying C++ model, but for a task as simple as listing functions it should be enough.

---

That said, I would question the usefulness of the project: if the documentation can be generated by a simple parser, then it is redundant with the code. And redundancy is at best, useless, and worst dangerous: it introduces the potential threat of desynchronization...

If the function is tricky enough that its use requires documentation, then a developer, who knows the limitations and al, has to write this documentation.

Comment: Yes. I mean, I plan on writing the implementation, but I just figured if I could write something that would lay out the framework for this documentation I could save some time. For example, if the script could determine the return types, parameters, etc. (Specifically for doxygen's sake), then all I would have to do is run through and add descriptions of what the functions are doing.

Obviously, for more complicated functions, I would still need to go through and judge where comments are needed on a line by line basis.

Comment: @Robert: Ah! got it. Do you have a fancy IDE ? I don't use doxygen myself, but it seems to me that a number of IDE support the automatic generation of those skeletons. Perhaps could you ask about this for your IDE :)