# How to identify C function definition with its datatype and name of argument in Python using Regular Expression?

Tags: python

I have Tried this regular expression for detection function but it's also detects function declaration.

```
result=re.match(^\s*('?:(?:inline|static)\s+){0,2}(?!else|typedef|return)\w+\s+\*?\s*(\w+)\s*\([^0]+\)\s*;?',Line)
```

Also I want to know the datatypes and name of function argument.How to do that using Regular Expression?

Comment: Here's one of the dupes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577425/using-regular-expressions-in-python-to-determine-c-functions-and-their-paramet. It relates to C++, but you probably need a full-scale parser for C, too.

Comment: Your regex also detects all kinds of other things, e.g. `/* ...` `Copyright MIT (1997) */` or `sizeof strlen(argv[1])` or `unsigned int (*p)[3]` or `char typedef (*string_t)`.

Comment: @melpomene- yes I know that it's also detects some false.Please tell me how to do that?